# How do I simulate the forces acting on this hydraulic system?

Tags: physics, animation, simulations

I've been trying to create an algorithm to simulate a specific hydraulic suspension system for animating a car rig. Below are the schematics for the hydraulic system:
[image: hydraulic system]

*All same-color lines are separate hydraulic systems. The dots are pivots, and the other symbols are springs and dampers.*

The input/output cylinders' position is controlled by the rigid body simulation of the animation software (yes, this isn't technically about a *game*, but my question wouldn't be any different if it was). The Cylinders can also affect the rigid body simulation by applying force to the wheels (which are part of the rigid body simulation). Each time-step, the positions of the input/output cylinders are gathered from the rigid body simulation, and my algorithm must use this position information, as well as the position information from the previous time-step, to determine how much force to apply to each input/output cylinder. I created an algorithm that works for each hydraulic subsystem (each separate color in the diagram) *individually*, but not all systems simultaneously. Here's how that algorithm works:

1. Get change in input cylinder displacement from previous time-step
2. Distribute displacement change evenly across all connected cylinders
3. Calculate forces on connected cylinders due to displacement acting on springs/dampers
4. Re-distribute displacement of connected cylinders proportional to force exerted on cylinder (i.e a cylinder that receives 20% of the total force will receive 80% of the total displacement, since the force is acting against the cylinder's displacement)
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 until either a maximum number of iterations is reached, or the variance in forces between iterations drops below a certain threshold
6. Set force on input/output cylinder to (total force in system) / (number of cylinders)

This method only works on a single isolated system, since the separate systems are mechanically linked. For example, if the red and purple input/output cylinders were fully compressed, then, during the initial iteration, the bottom left connected cylinder would be displaced in two opposite directions, and the other cylinders would be displaced in such a way that wouldn't preserve the volume of the fluid. This is the core of my question: **how can I solve for the force acting on ALL input/output cylinders, while still following preservation of mass, in a single discrete time-step?**

Comment: This looks like a question the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) or [Engineering StackExchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) sites might be able to help with. If you choose to ask on one of those sites, be sure to delete the copy here, so that all the best answers are centralized in one place.